Proof involving integrals, binomial coefficients and Legendre polynomials
I'm currently working on a research paper involving L-moments statistics. This is the first time for me working on that subject.
I stumbled upon this article mentioning a very important equality, named (2.2) on this picture (taken from page 3 of 1) and named (2) in my post. I really don't know how to prove this equality. I'm feeling dumb because the author does not even give a proof.
To write that here and for people that don't want to use the image, I want to prove that the L-moments, where the $r$th L-moment denoted $\lambda_r$ defined as,
$$
\lambda_r = r^{-1} \sum_{k=0}^{r-1} (-1)^k \binom{r-1}{k} \mathbb{E}X_{r-k:r} \quad \quad (1) \\
\text{ with } \mathbb{E}X_{j:r} = \frac{r!}{(j-1)!(r-j)!} \int_{0}^{1} x \left[ F(x) \right]^{j-1} \left[ 1 - F(x) \right]^{r-j} dF(x)
$$
could also be written as,
$$
\lambda_r = \int_{0}^{1} x(F) P^*_{r-1}(F) dF \quad \quad (2) \\ 
\text{ where } P^*_{r-1}(F) = \sum_{k=0}^{r-1} p^*_{r-1,k} F^k \\
\text{ and }p^*_{r,k} = (-1)^{r-k} \binom{r}{k} \binom{r+k}{k}
$$

Note 1 : the author says that $P^*_{r-1}$ is a shifted Legendre polynomial, I found on Wikipedia's page of Legendre polynomials this expression for a non-shifted polynomial that looks the same,
$$
P_{r}(x) = \sum_{k=0}^{r} \binom{r}{k} \binom{r+k}{k} \left(\dfrac{x-1}{2}\right)^k
$$
and the shift is,
$$
P^*_r(x) = P_r(2x+1) = \sum_{k=0}^{r} \binom{r}{k} \binom{r+k}{k} x^k
$$
the difference is that the $(-1)^{r-k}$ term does not appear.

Note 2 : the author says "Substituting [the $\mathbb{E}X_{j:r}$] expression in definition (1), expanding the binomials in F(x) and summing the coefficients of each power of F(x) gives (2)." which is basically his proof... I wanted to expand the $(1-F(x)^{r-j}$ with the binomial theorem, but I don't know what to do with that.

Note 3 : I've noticed that when you plug the $\mathbb{E}X_{j:r}$ in (1), the binomials coefficients and the $r^{-1}$ at the beginning gives, in the sum,
$$
r^{-1} \binom{r-1}{k} \frac{r!}{((r-k)-1)!(r-(r-k))!} = r^{-1} \binom{r-1}{k} \frac{r!}{((r-1)-k)!k!} = \binom{r-1}{k}^2
$$
and there's another expression of Legendre polynomials involving squared binomial coefficients found also in 3,
$$
P_r(x) = \dfrac{1}{2^r} \sum_{k=0}^{r} \binom{r}{k}^2 (x-1)^{r-k} (x+1)^k
$$
but I don't know what to do with that again.

I really need to find that because this a key stone for deriving an estimator for the L-moments after.
Thanks all,
Thomas
